# Random space in Rails DateTime when using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a method in my Event model:

```
  def when
    self.starts_at.strftime("%a %b %e @ %-I:%M")
  end
```

which outputs correctly in the rails console or on a webpage.

However, doing an rspec test like this:

```
  it "has simple date display" do
    game = FactoryGirl.build(:event, starts_at: DateTime.parse("1/1/2014 3:30pm"))
    game.when.should == "Wed Jan 1 @ 3:30"
  end
```

fails, because of:

```
1) Event has simple date display
     Failure/Error: event.when.should == "Wed Jan 1 @ 3:30"
       expected: "Wed Jan 1 @ 3:30"
            got: "Wed Jan  1 @ 3:30" (using ==)
```

Why is there a random space in my formatted DateTime? Shouldn't the same DateTime code be loaded/running for tests and console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `%e` format directive, which is for the blank-padded day of month. It sounds like you want the unpadded day of the month directive, which is `%-d`. [Here are the docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime).

Answer (score 2):

The reason your test is failing is because the `%e` directives in [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) is:

> %e - Day of the month, blank-padded ( 1..31)

So the statement `DateTime.parse("1/1/2014 3:30pm").strftime("%a %b %e @ %-I:%M")` yields `Wed Jan   1 @ 3:30` (with extra space prepended for days between 1 through 9).

You could use `%d` directive instead which gives day of month, zero-padded.  E.g.

```
# Event model
def when
  self.starts_at.strftime("%a %b %d @ %-I:%M")
end
```

Then in your spec:

```
it "has simple date display" do
  game = FactoryGirl.build(:event, starts_at: DateTime.parse("1/1/2014 3:30pm"))
  game.when.should == "Wed Jan 01 @ 3:30"
end
```

Comment: +1, but I gave the accept to @Mori because he led me to %-e which is what I was after.